# Woocommerce cart shows as empty

Tags: woocommerce

My woocommerce version is 2.2.10 (updated to latest version just now)

For non logged in users, the cart always shows "Empty". Earlier it was working fine, before the update.

Thanks..

Comment: This [link](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201764603-Shopping-cart-showing-as-empty-for-guests) may solve your issue

Comment: basically it's an issue with cache I think, but I haven't installed any plugin that they mentioned int that article..

Comment: I have installed in my localhost wordpress site with latest woocommerce 2.2.10. Cart is showing products. No error. Check the theme or plugins. There may be conflict with Theme or Plugin.

Comment: thanks for your time, btw its working fine in my local too.. problem is in server only..